# Drupal 8: get the value from a disabled field in a twig template

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8, paragraphs

I'm using the Paragraphs module to create components, i then make a content type and add the Paragraph as a reference field.

The form of the Paragraph has a field (a list) where a content creator can select a color name for a background color for the div. Each Paragraph has 3 values (pacific_blue, smokey_white, white).

However, i'm trying to get the selected value without displaying it on the site.

**As long as the field is not disabled i can get the value using this code and add the class to style the div with the right background color:**

```
<div class="c14a {{ content.group_wrap.field_color_backgrou d.0["#markup"] }}">
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
      {{ content }}
  </div>
</div>
```

So how do i get the value of a field that is disabled in '**manage display**'?

Thx...

Comment: why do you want to disable the display value?

Comment: No, if the user (while adding content) chooses a particular background color from the list. I want to catch that in the twig template file and add the class to the div (see class c14a)

Comment: You can't use jquery or javascript to perform that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just implemented similar functionality to a site I am building. In my case the content creator can make a selection from a dropdown and depending on the selection a particular class is applied to a div.

My issue was similar in that I wanted to extract the raw value of the field without display the field on the front end. The problem I encountered was that disabling the field prevented me from getting the raw field value in the twig template.

The solution that I came up with was to use a preprocess function instead of disabling the field which allowed me to remove the field from the front end while still allowing me to access the field value in my template.

```
function HOOK_preprocess_YOUR_FIELD(&$variables)
{
    unset($variables['items']);
}
```

Hope this answer is of some help to anyone out there